# how to Use TLS1.1 in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, ssl

I have python 2.7.3 in my server and i want to use TLS1.1 [python2.7.3 supports only TLS1.0].

I can't upgrade my python version because it impacts others.
I tried with backports but it give the error.

Here is my code

```
import backports.ssl as ssl
import requests

def do_it():  
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
        url = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/sobjects'
        response = s.get(url,headers=_headers)
        response = requests.get(url,headers=_headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_it()
```

Comment: Could you please describe the error you're getting with backports ?

Comment: I am getting below Error:home/ubuntu/netskope/service/nsenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.pyc in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version)
    253                     ca_certs=None, server_hostname=None,
    254                     ssl_version=None):
--> 255     ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(_openssl_versions[ssl_version])
    256     if certfile:
    257         keyfile = keyfile or certfile  # Match behaviour of the normal python ssl library

KeyError: 5

Comment: It is not unlikely that the problem is not the version of Python by itself but the version of the underlying OpenSSL library. For TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 support OpenSSL 1.0.1 is needed and if you are still stuck with OpenSSL 1.0.0 or 0.9.8 backports will not help (check `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"`). But you might try installing another Python in parallel so that others can continue to use the old version while you are using a new version.